# divisibility of the sum of two consecutive primes

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

For even integers half are divisible by 4, one-third by 6, and one-quarter by 8.  For the sum of two consecutive primes, can one say that the divisibility follows the same ratios for division by all even numbers?  Has anyone examined this?

Comment: It is definitely not true. The reason for this relationship over even integers is since the even integers are the integers multiplied by 2.

Comment: One could compare such divisibility by counting how many sums of two consecutive primes are divisible by 4, by 6, by 8,and by other even numbers.  Would there be any surprises as there was in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02443.pdf